# how to do custom filtering and custom pagination

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, grid, filtering

I am not using Entity framework, i have created custom Data Access Layer.
i want to do custom filtering and custom pagination.

does grid.mvc supports custom pagination and custom filtering?
i have checked http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/documentation documentation, but can not find how to do it.

i have tried

```
EnablePaging = true;
Pager.PageSize = 10;
```

but it will do pagination on already paged data.

if anybody had done it, please suggest how it can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with grid.mvc, but you can do paging and filtering on virtually any sequence in .NET using LINQ.

```
var items = new List<string>();

// Add 10 items for testing
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    items.Add("item" + i.ToString());
}

var pagedAndFilteredItems = items
    .Where(x => x != "item0") // Filter the first item from the sequence
    .Skip(3) // Number of items to skip over
    .Take(3) // Number of items to put into the current view.
    .ToList(); // Executes the query

// pagedAndFilteredItems now contains
// "item4"
// "item5"
// "item6"
// Which corresponds to the second page if your page size is 3
```

You could then only provide 1 page at a time to grid.mvc. You might have to build your own next and back links, but if you are pulling data from an external source, this is far more scalable than providing the entire dataset to the grid.

Of course, another option is to do the filtering in LINQ as shown with the Where clause and then have grid.mvc do the pagination.